# Opening a link inside a div in the same div

Tags: php, javascript, html, navigation

I am trying to make a `div` where I include PHP web pages into it, however when I click any link inside the `div`, it loads in new window.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I also tried using an `iframe` instead of a `div` but it caused other problems.

HTML code:

```
<div id="cover5">
    <div id="warning">
        <?php include 'SignIn.php'; ?>
        <p align="center">
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:cover5();">Home</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
function cover5() {
    var cover = document.getElementById('cover5');
    if (vis) {
        vis = 0;
        cover.style.display='block';
    }
    else {
        vis = 1;
        cover.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: You want that when a user clicks on a link within your included code, the new page loads within the `div#warning` and not within the browser the user?

Comment: lookup AJAX, that's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a distinction bitween the client-side and the server-side of a Web application.

`<?php include 'SignIn.php'; ?>` is a server-side command, because of the `<?php ?>`, which means that the user will never see that line exactly.

If your `SignIn.php` file contains for example `<a href="go-there.php">my link</a>`, the user will only get the ouput of that inclusion, i.e.

```
<div id="warning">
    <a href="go-there.php">my link</a
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the link, his browser will load it as if this `<a />` would have been *hard written* within your HTML code directly, and then open it in a new window.

I don't no how to do it using native JS, but with jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#warning a").each(function() {
        $("#warning").load($(this).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To render html from a specific link within an element on the page you need to run an `ajax` `GET` call, and load the html. Then insert the response in your `div`.

using jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){                    //calls function when anchor is clicked
  var link = $(this).prop("src");           //finds the link from the anchor
  $.get(link,function(data, status, xhr){   //makes an ajax call to the page
    $("#myDiv").html(data);                 //replaces the html of #myDiv with the returned page
  });
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="cover5">
    <div id="links">
        <p align="center">
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:cover5();">Home</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="warning">
        <?php include 'SignIn.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS code:

```
function cover5() {
    var cover = document.getElementById('warning');
    if (vis) {
        vis = 0;
        cover.style.display='block';
    }
    else {
        vis = 1;
        cover.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Whenever an user click on the link in "links" div it will call JS function "**cover5()**"

You can use jQuery or ajax to pop-up "warning" div

In your code you added the links to the **worning** div so as when in second time ti will hide all the links form there.